# I want to check if the value was repeated above. How I can do it?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

So I have the next code:

```
SELECT distinct NVL( l.city, ' '), e.last_name || ' ' || e.first_name
FROM locations l
FULL JOIN departments d
    ON d.location_id = l.location_id
FULL JOIN employees e
    ON e.department_id = d.department_id
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
NVL(L.CITY,'')      E.LAST_NAME||''||E.FIRST_NAME                 
------------------- ----------------------------------------------                                                              
1) Seattle                                                                      
2) Seattle             Kochhar Neena                                 
3) Oxford              Zlotkey Eleni                                 
4) Oxford              Abel Ellen                                    
5) Oxford              Vargas Jonathon                                                        
6) Oxford              Grovlin Gus
```

I want it to not display the line where is only City and no Lastname if there is a line where this city is mentioned. For example, I have row

```
Seattle                   Kochhar Neena
```

because Seattle is already displayed, I don't want to see the first line. However, if there is no row with city and last_name, there should be line with just the city.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Rows in sql have no 'order' as such - other than that expressly defined within the query. So 'already' has no meaning in this context. Also, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of analytic sql should do the trick.

```
SQL> with your_data as
  2  (
  3  SELECT distinct
  4    l.city city,
  5    e.last_name || ' ' || e.first_name name
  6  FROM hr.locations l FULL JOIN
  7       hr.departments d ON d.location_id = l.location_id FULL JOIN
  8       hr.employees e ON e.department_id = d.department_id
  9  )
 10  select *
 11  from
 12  (
 13  select
 14    y.*,
 15    count(*) over ( partition by city ) as seq
 16  from your_data y
 17  )
 18  where seq = 1 or ( seq > 1 and name != ' ' )
 19  order by 1,2;

CITY                           NAME                                                  SEQ
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------- ----------
Beijing                                                                                1
Bern                                                                                   1
Bombay                                                                                 1
Geneva                                                                                 1
Hiroshima                                                                              1
London                         Mavris Susan                                            1
Mexico City                                                                            1
Munich                         Baer Hermann                                            1
Oxford                         Abel Ellen                                             34
Oxford                         Ande Sundar                                            34
Oxford                         Banda Amit                                             34
Oxford                         Bates Elizabeth                                        34
Oxford                         Bernstein David                                        34
```

Full tutorial on these techniques here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cjxYMxa1e4&list=PLJMaoEWvHwFIUwMrF4HLnRksF0H8DHGtt

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number` analytical function based on pks.

```
Select city, ename from 
 (SELECT distinct NVL( l.city, ' ') as city, 
         trim(e.last_name || ' ' || e.first_name) as ename, 
         Row_number()  over 
         (partiotion by l.location_id order by e.department_id desc nulls last) as rn 
   FROM locations l 
        FULL JOIN departments d
    ON d.location_id = l.location_id 
        FULL JOIN employees e
    ON e.department_id = d.department_id) 
 Where case when ename is null and rn != 1
           Then 0 Else 1
           End = 1
```

Cheers!!